# how to check character by character in a line if upper case or lower case and count the upper case and lower case?

Tags: python-3.x

I have tried using isupper and islower but no luck.Can you please suggest a method.I have tried using islower but it returns some number not true or false.

```
s=input()
size=len(s)
for i in range(0,size):
    print(s[i].isupper)
```

expected output?

Comment: What do you mean you've tried `isupper()` and `islower()` - `'A'.islower() # False`? Show your code and the issues you get and you will likely get more help.

Comment: @AChampion i assume 'a'.isupper returns false but insted some number not even 0 or 1

Comment: You need to actually called the function, so you need parens, e.g. `s[i].isupper()`. What you have will just print the function reference, e.g. `<built-in method isupper of str object at 0x1003caab0>`.

Comment: so what is the correct method? @AChampion

Comment: Call the function `s[i].isupper()` - notice the parens at the end!!!

Comment: ok i didnt notice that..i was meaning to call it as function..now i realise my mistake @AChampion thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will count total lowercase and uppercase character

```
s=input()
size=len(s)
upper = 0
lower = 0
for i in range(0,size):
    if(s[i].isupper()):
      upper += 1
    elif (s[i].islower()):
      lower += 1
    else:
      pass

print("total upper = {}".format(upper))
print("total lower = {}".format(lower))
```